# unable to get checkbox array to submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I have the following form(truncated)

```
    <%= form_for(daysevent, :html => { :class => "form-inline"} ) do |f| %>
    <fieldset>
    <div class="control-group">
        <%= f.label :start_date, :class => 'control-label' %>
        <div class="controls">
          <%= f.text_field :start_date, 'data-behavior' => 'datepicker1' %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group">
        <%= f.label :end_date, :class => 'control-label' %>
        <div class="controls">
          <%= f.text_field :end_date, 'data-behavior' => 'datepicker2' %>
        </div>
      </div>
    Locations for this date:<br/>
    <% daysevent.event.locations.each do |l|%>         
        <%= check_box_tag 'location_ids[]', l.id, true -%><%= h l.name -%><br/>    
    <% end %> 
    <%= f.submit 'Create Date' %>
    </fieldset>
    <% end %>
```

I'm trying to get the list of location checkboxes to come through in an array of IDs but its not working, in my create method return render :text => params[:days_event] is just returning start_date and end_date. I've only been doing rails for a few months so its probably something simple but all help his appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not sending values of checkboxes in the `params[:days_event]` but in `params[:locations_ids]`. You can check debug output from `rails server` and you will see parsed `params` hash.

If you want to send them along then change the checkboxes to:

```
<%= check_box_tag "days_event[location_ids][]" .... %>
```